# Write user selected page control values in an xml file through javascript and store in client machine

Tags: javascript, asp.net, xml

my problem is that---------i have many input controls on my form, in my asp.net multiuser web application, when user enter values in half of the controls and power is switched off,user looses all of entered data ,and he has to fill the form from begining .
so i want to store all user inputs in an xml file through javascript on lost focus of each control(every time regenerating the new file and deleting old file) and store that in a file on client side.i have tried it to store in cookie ,but the xml string size is more than cookie size limit.
also i want to store the xml file data to database at last from server side.

so is there any problem in my approach ? or any other way to solve my purpose ?
any suggesion will be appreciated .

thank you.

Comment: Could you break up the design so that you don't have so many controls on the same section, and then save the values to a database on postback between sections? You could achieve this through different tabs so that the user thinks that there are multiple sections, and therefore wouldn't mind the post back, even though it is all one page.

Comment: i am already having 4 tabs/steps(web forms) ,so i can not break up the design any more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this way as a base. This is using only js. Its better to save as json than xml on the clientside localstorage. No JQuery:

```
<form>
    <input id="txt1" onchange="saveDraft()" type="text" />
    <input id="txt2" onchange="saveDraft()" type="text" />
    <input id="txt3" onchange="saveDraft()" type="text" />
    <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
var elements = ["txt1","txt2","txt3"];

function saveDraft(){
    var values= new Object;
    for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
        values[elements[i]] = document.getElementById(elements[i]).value;
    }
    localStorage["draft"] = JSON.stringify(values);
}

window.onload = function (){
    restoreDraft();
}

function restoreDraft(){
    var values;
    if(localStorage["draft"] ){
        values = JSON.parse(localStorage["draft"]);
    }
    else
        return;
    if(confirm('Do you want to restore saved draft?')){
        for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
            document.getElementById(elements[i]).value = values[elements[i]];
        }
        localStorage["draft"] ='';
    }           
}
</script>
```

Comment: thank you for answer, this is alternate way(more efficient ? ) as saving multiple control values in one cookie,but i wanted to use xml because i think storing the xml directly to database(from server side in last postback) is much easier and efficient ?